# Target ::after in :hover state

Tags: html, css

How can I target the ::after element on :hover?

```
<button class="panel-watch">
Watch online
::after
</button>
```

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to do it:

```
button.panel-watch:hover ::after {
border-color:white transparent transparent transparent!important;
}
```

I would just re-jig the html/css to fit better but it comes out of the box like this.

Comment: Don't leave a space in between. `selector:hover::after` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between:

```
button.panel-watch:hover::after {}
```

---

A space in between `hover` and `::after` means the selector is looking for a child element of `button.panel-watch`.